# Знаки препинания при повторе конструкции

Tags: пунктуация

*Не думайте, что вы воспитываете ребёнка только тогда, когда с ним разговариваете, или поучаете его, или приказываете ему — вы воспитываете его, даже когда вас нет дома.*

Будет ли являться отдельной грамматической основой повтор фразы "вы воспитываете"? И помогите, пожалуйста, найти правило постановки тире в данном случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***(1) Не думайте, (2)что вы воспитываете ребёнка только тогда, (3)когда с ним разговариваете, или поучаете его, или приказываете ему, — (4) вы воспитываете его, (5) даже когда вас нет дома.***

В этом сложном предложении 5 простых предложений (предикативных основ), связь между ними подчинительная и бессоюзная.

Предложение делится на **две смысловые группы** с помощью тире, которое обозначает бессоюзную связь между ними.

**Повтор** является конструктивным приемом, с помощью которого обозначается противопоставление двух групп.

Между двумя смысловыми группами ставится **единый знак "запятая - тире"**, обозначающий "перелом" конструкции.

О "переломе" говорится в правилах Розенталя (тема СПП и БСП), например:

*Пусть я даже **ошибаюсь**, — что ж, **ошибаться** свойственно человеку; Он замолчал, но не потому, что **ему не хватало** слов, — **ему не хватало** дыхания;*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

3. Запятая и тире ставятся **для обозначения «перелома» первоначальной конструкции,** для указания, «с одной стороны, на расчлененность предложения, а с другой — на то, что та его часть, которая следует за этим знаком препинания, делает структурный поворот от предшествующей части под некоторым, большим или меньшим углом.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=152#pp152

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: Здесь нет перелома конструкции.